# CRITICAL WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:31019)

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

Я попытался запустить свое приложение на vps от linode, оно заработало, но не полностью. Дело в том, что при нажатии на кнопку приложение формировало из базы данных таблицу xlsx и отправляло ее по почте пользователю. В итоге таблица-то формируется, через WinSCP я вижу файлик, ctrl+c , ctrl+v на рабочий стол, открыл проверил: в нем все формируется верно, но почему то не отправляется по почте, более того если я удалю ту часть кода, с отправкой по почте, проблемы это не решит - он все равно покажет ошибку **502 bad gateway**, а бывает и не покажет ошибки вовсе, просто не отправит. Смотрел логи gninx там все старое, по времени ошибки не подходит ( часа 2 назад все записи сделаны ), но на всякий случай напишу: **upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream**. Я совсем новичок, это мой первый деплой **не** на heroku, так что кроме этих логов в /var/log ничего больше и не нашел, непривычно отлаживать без удобного console log на heroku. Gunicorn выдает следующее: **[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:31019)**

UPD: как выяснилось такая же история с некоторыми другими опциями сайта, что-то нормально работает, что-то видает ту же ошибку, иногда не выдает, возможно как-то зависит от proxy_connect_timeout, proxy_read_timeout в nginx конфиге, но моя программа никогда не работала больше пары секунд, даже одной на локалхосте. Не представляю как ей может не хватать стандартных 30 секунд в юникорне и 60 в nginx

nginx настроен так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 172.105.84.133;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если ошибку выдаёт gunicorn, то nginx тут совершенно ни при чём и измеряйте время работы вашего кода

Comment: 1) почту настраивали? Если нормально не настроили возможно почта попросту отбрасывается принимающим сервером. 2) логи бэкенда проверяли? Его корректную работу без nginx проверяли? 3) Вся приведенная вами информация говорит о том, что nginx тут вообще не виноват.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена переходом на новый сервер (amazon lightsail), Linode по умолчанию не разрешает отправку почты через себя, порты 465, 22 (и кажется 587, не уверен) закрыты. Точно также порты закрыты и у Джино (Jino).